# Install Order in K8s

Tags: kubernetes

I have a set of yaml files which are of different Kinds like

1 PVC

1 PV (The above PVC claims this PV)

1 Service

1 StatefulSet Object (The above Service is for this Stateful Set

1 Config Map (The above Stateful set uses this config map

Does the Install order of these objects matter to bring up an application using these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do `kubectl apply -f dir` on a directory containing all of those files then it should work, at least if you have the latest version as [there have been bugs raised and addressed in this area](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/64203).

However, there are some dependencies which aren't hard dependencies and [for which there is discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/16448). For this reason some are choosing to [order the resources themselves](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/16448#issuecomment-454218437) or use a deployment tool like [helm which deploys](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1228) resources [in a certain order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957676/helm-install-in-certain-order).