# What's the order of execution of the yamls in the helm templates/ directory?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am a helm/tiller rookie. My chart directory looks like:

```
$ helm create mychart

$ tree mychart
mychart
├── Chart.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── daemonset.yaml
│   ├── ingress.yaml
│   ├── ingress_external.yaml
│   ├── ingress_path.yaml
│   ├── rbac.yaml
│   └── service.yaml
└── tests
    ├── daemonset_test.yaml
    ├── ingress_external_test.yaml
    ├── ingress_test.yaml
    └── service_test.yaml
```

On doing an install of this chart, is the order of execution of the templates well-defined or are the yaml files under templates/ directory executed in a non-deterministic order? Are the templates executed in alphabetical order?

Thank you.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957676/helm-install-in-certain-order/51962615#51962615)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Helm install in certain order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957676/helm-install-in-certain-order)

Answer (score 1):

Order was added in v3.1.0

> ```
>   // expectation is sorted by kind (unknown is last) and within each
> ```
>
> group of same kind, the order is kept
> {"cm,clusterRole,clusterRoleBinding,Unknown,Unknown2", InstallOrder,
> "01aAz!u2u1t3"},

https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/6842/commits/4d8160eedf43db8ed137