# helm install chart with multiple deployments - parallel

Tags: kubernetes-helm

When installing a helm chart with multiple deployments (more the one deployments, pods, etc) - does it run in parallel?

For example if the helm should install 4 deployments and need to download 4 different images
does it going to happen in parallel of it will download sequentially?

Thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Helm install in certain order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957676/helm-install-in-certain-order)