# Helm 3 Deployment Order of Kubernetes Service Catalog Resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using Helm v3.3.0, with a Kubernetes 1.16.

The cluster has the [Kubernetes Service Catalog](https://svc-cat.io/docs/) installed, so external services implementing the Open Service Broker API spec can be instantiated as K8S resources - as `ServiceInstance`s and `ServiceBinding`s.

`ServiceBinding`s reflect as K8S `Secret`s and contain the binding information of the created external service. These secrets are usually mapped into the Docker containers as environment variables or volumes in a K8S `Deployment`.

Now I am using Helm to deploy my Kubernetes resources, and I read [here](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#operational-aspects-of-using-dependencies) that...

> The [Helm] install order of Kubernetes types is given by the enumeration InstallOrder in [kind_sorter.go](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/release-3.3/pkg/releaseutil/kind_sorter.go)

In that file, the order does neither mention `ServiceInstance` nor `ServiceBinding` as resources, and that would mean that Helm installs these resource types **after** it has installed any of its InstallOrder list - in particular `Deployment`s. That seems to match the output of `helm install --dry-run --debug` run on my chart, where the order indicates that the K8S Service Catalog resources are applied last.

**Question:** What I cannot understand is, why my `Deployment` does **not** fail to install with Helm.
After all my `Deployment` resource seems to be deployed before the `ServiceBinding` is. And it is the `Secret` generated out of the `ServiceBinding` that my `Deployment` references. I would expect it to fail, since the `Secret` is not there yet, when the `Deployment` is getting installed. But that is not the case.

Is that just a timing glitch / lucky coincidence, or is this something I can rely on, and why?

Thanks!

Comment: In fact your `Deployment` is failing at the start with `Status: CreateContainerConfigError`. Your `Deployment` is created before `Secret` from the `ServiceBinding`. It's only working as it was recreated when the `Secret` from `ServiceBinding` was available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment I posted:

> In fact your `Deployment` is failing at the start with `Status: CreateContainerConfigError`. Your `Deployment` is created before `Secret` from the `ServiceBinding`. It's only working as it was recreated when the `Secret` from `ServiceBinding` was available.

I wanted to give more insight with example of why the `Deployment` didn't fail.

What is happening (simplified in order):

- `Deployment` -> created and spawned a `Pod`
- `Pod` -> failing pod with status: `CreateContainerConfigError` by lack of `Secret`
- `ServiceBinding` -> created `Secret` in a background
- `Pod` gets the required `Secret` and starts

Previously mentioned `InstallOrder` will leave `ServiceInstace` and `ServiceBinding` as last by comment on [line 147](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/release-3.3/pkg/releaseutil/kind_sorter.go#L147).

---

### Example

Assuming that:

- There is a working Kubernetes cluster
- Helm3 installed and ready to use

Following guides:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Instal Service Catalog using Helm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/service-catalog/install-service-catalog-using-helm/)*
- *[Magalix.com: Blog: Kubernetes Service Catalog](https://www.magalix.com/blog/kubernetes-service-catalog-101)*

There is a Helm chart with following files in `templates/` directory:

- `ServiceInstance`
- `ServiceBinding`
- `Deployment`

Files:

`ServiceInstance.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: servicecatalog.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceInstance
metadata:
  name: example-instance
spec:
  clusterServiceClassExternalName: redis
  clusterServicePlanExternalName: 5-0-4
```

`ServiceBinding.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: servicecatalog.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceBinding
metadata:
  name: example-binding
spec:
  instanceRef:
    name: example-instance
```

`Deployment.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ubuntu
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ubuntu
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ubuntu
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ubuntu
        image: ubuntu
        command:
        - sleep 
        - "infinity" 
        # part below responsible for getting secret as env variable
        env: 
        - name: DATA
          valueFrom: 
            secretKeyRef:
              name: example-binding
              key: host
```

Applying above resources to check what is happening can be done in 2 ways:

- First method is to use `timestamp` from `$ kubectl get RESOURCE -o yaml`
- Second method is to use `$ kubectl get RESOURCE --watch-only=true`

---

#### First method

As said previously the `Pod` from the `Deployment` couldn't start as `Secret` was not available when the `Pod` tried to spawn. After the `Secret` was available to use, the `Pod` started.

The statuses this `Pod` had were the following:

- `Pending`
- `ContainerCreating`
- `CreateContainerConfigError`
- `Running`

This is a table with timestamps of `Pod` and `Secret`:

```
|                  Pod                      |                Secret                     |
|-------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------|
| creationTimestamp: "2020-08-23T19:54:47Z" |                   -                       |
|                   -                       | creationTimestamp: "2020-08-23T19:54:55Z" |
| startedAt: "2020-08-23T19:55:08Z"         |                   -                       |
```

You can get this timestamp by invoking below commands:

- `$ kubectl get pod pod_name -n namespace -o yaml`
- `$ kubectl get secret secret_name -n namespace -o yaml`

You can also get get additional information with:

- `$ kubectl get event -n namespace`
- `$ kubectl describe pod pod_name -n namespace`

#### Second method

This method requires preparation before running Helm chart. Open another terminal window (for this particular case 2) and run:

- `$ kubectl get pod -n namespace --watch-only | while read line ; do echo -e "$(gdate +"%H:%M:%S:%N")\t $line" ; done`
- `$ kubectl get secret -n namespace --watch-only | while read line ; do echo -e "$(gdate +"%H:%M:%S:%N")\t $line" ; done`

After that apply your Helm chart.

> Disclaimer!
>
> Above commands will watch for changes in resources and display them with a timestamp from the OS. Please remember that this command is only for example purposes.

The output for `Pod`:

```
21:54:47:534823000   NAME                      READY   STATUS                       RESTARTS    AGE
21:54:47:542107000   ubuntu-65976bb789-l48wz   0/1     Pending                      0           0s
21:54:47:553799000   ubuntu-65976bb789-l48wz   0/1     Pending                      0           0s
21:54:47:655593000   ubuntu-65976bb789-l48wz   0/1     ContainerCreating            0           0s
-> 21:54:52:001347000    ubuntu-65976bb789-l48wz   0/1     CreateContainerConfigError   0           4s
21:55:09:205265000   ubuntu-65976bb789-l48wz   1/1     Running                      0           22s
```

The output for `Secret`:

```
21:54:47:385714000   NAME                            TYPE                 DATA   AGE
21:54:47:393145000   sh.helm.release.v1.example.v1   helm.sh/release.v1   1      0s
21:54:47:719864000   sh.helm.release.v1.example.v1   helm.sh/release.v1   1      0s
21:54:51:182609000   understood-squid-redis          Opaque               1      0s
21:54:52:001031000   understood-squid-redis          Opaque               1      0s
-> 21:54:55:686461000    example-binding                 Opaque               6      0s
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Answer: Helm install in certain order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51962615/12257134)*
- *[Alibabacloud.com: Helm charts and templates hooks and tests part 3](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/helm-charts-and-templates-hooks-and-tests-part-3_595650)*

Answer (score 1):

So to answer my own question (and thanks to @dawid-kruk and the folks on Service Catalog Sig on Slack):

- In fact, the initial start of my `Pod`s (the ones referencing the `Secret` created out of the `ServiceBinding`) fails! It fails because the `Secret` is actually not there the moment K8S tries to start the pods.
- Kubernetes has a self-healing mechanism, in the sense that it tries (and retries) to reach the target state of the cluster as described by the various deployed resources.
- By Kubernetes retrying to get the pods running, eventually (when the `Secret` is finally there) all conditions will be satisfied to make the pods start up nicely. Therefore, eventually, evth. is running as it should.

How could this be streamlined? One possibility would be for Helm to include the custom resources `ServiceBinding` and `ServiceInstance` into its ordered list of installable resources and install them early in the installation phase.

But even without that, Kubernetes actually deals with it just fine. The order of installation (in this case) really does not matter. And that is a good thing!