# how to run pods and jobs in specific order

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I need to run pods and jobs in a specific order

I have this chart structure

```
my-chart/
  Chart.yaml 
  Values.yaml 
  templates/
    module1 /
        deployment1.yaml 
        service1.yaml    
        job1.yaml
    module2 /
        deployment2.yaml 
        service2.yaml    
        job2.yaml
```

I want job1 start running once all pod replicas related to module1 are ready
and the job2 start running once all pod replicas related to module2 are ready

I try post-install and post-upgrade hooks but this will start jobs after all pods of module1 and module2 are all ready

I found one solution that is not recommended is to use "kubectl" in "initContainers" to verify all the pods related to module1 are ready or not.

Are there any additional recommendations or suggestions please ?

Comment: Have you looked at [Chart Hooks](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/)?

Comment: yes but hooks does not resolve the above order expected

Comment: Have a look to this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51962615/21404450

Comment: Additionally, from the same link provided by @HiroCereal: `It is possible to define a weight for a hook which will help build a deterministic executing order. Weights are defined using the following annotation: "helm.sh/hook-weight": "5"`