# Helm dependency problem: dependencies among charts within an umbrella

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helmfile

I've got an umbrella chart which installs a few dependencies which, it turns out, have dependencies among themselves.

Umbrella:

- chart A
- chart B

Chart B creates a secret which gets used within chart B's configmap. It does fail to install as the secret cannot be found by the lookup helm function - run as part of B's templates - at installation time.

I am a bit puzzled as by reading these resources one would guess that all kub. objects definitions YAML frrom all charts within the umbrella are generated and grouped following a given order - where Secrets come before ConfigMap - and then executed.

https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#operational-aspects-of-using-dependencies

[Helm install in certain order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957676/helm-install-in-certain-order)

Comment: You tagged this with [helmfile]; are you actually using Helmfile, or just plain Helm?  Why and how are you using `lookup`?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: (I would normally expect all of the YAML templates from all of the subcharts to be rendered, then all of the resources sent to the cluster in the specified kind order; if you `lookup` a Secret that the same release is installing, it won't exist yet.)

Comment: I willclose my question - it just did not make any sense, the template used a (lookup) call which of course fails during the rendering as the other chart is being rendered as well and nothing has reached the Kub. API server yet, hence the secret cannot exist.

Comment: Please be aware, using `lookup` with `--dry-run` or `helm template` would result in an error.