# Is it possible to execute the yaml files in the templates directory sequentially for a helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helmfile

I have a custom query where I need to install istio and create a gateway resource when doing helm install but right now it fails because without istio CRDs first installed, we cannot create a istio gateway custom resource.

I can see all the yaml files in the templates dir gets applied when we run helm install/upgrade. Is there any way where I can stop the parallel execution of yaml file such if the previous yaml deployment manifest is successfull then apply the next one?

Comment: Does [Helm install in certain order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957676/helm-install-in-certain-order) answer your question?  (TL;DR: resources are sorted by `Kind` but otherwise install together.)  CRDs within a chart [have special handling](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/custom_resource_definitions/#install-a-crd-declaration-before-using-the-resource) but need to be put into their own directory.  You also tagged this with [tag:helmfile]; does its [`needs:`](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#dag-aware-installationdeletion-ordering-with-needs) cover this case?

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze but my use case is I have 3 yaml file and I want 1st to be applied and wait for sometime ( like 3minutes ) before it applies the next two yaml files from the templates directory. Is it possible to achieve this using helm

Comment: Neither using plain Helm nor Helmfile, no; neither has any sort of option for an arbitrary delay between install operations.